# Can I share my results published results/research on my personal website or Medium blog post?

Tags: publications, blog

Is it OK to share my results on Medium blog post or my personal website when I have signed a copyright form with IEEE or IET?

In the paper submission, I only shared the method and results. But I want to share the exact codes that I used to produce the result. Will it violate the copyright?

The second question is if I publish my result on my blog post before submitting my paper, will it cause any trouble with the reviewers or reviewing process?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you - probably yes but may depend on what you signed with your institution.

Should you - no - peer review exists for a reason, and also if you make your results public how can you then produce a paper from them - especially if someone else publishes a paper based on your results. so you can make the code available **after** publishing your paper...

Edit: Buffy said it best in one comment below: Exploit your work first **then** publish the background.

Comment: Hmmm. Mystified about the downvotes here.

Comment: @Buffy may be linked on how the other answer uses mine as it was voted up before that appeared... sometimes I just ignore downvoters...

Comment: Ignoring is a good policy. But still, mystified. A careful reading of both suggests they say the same thing fundamentally.

Comment: @Buffy I'm not the downvoter, but this answer says "Probably yes you can, **but you should not.**" The other answer says "Probably yes you can, and **you definitely should.**" So, I suspect others are not reading them as saying nearly the same thing.

Comment: @BryanKrause, read deeper. Exploit your work first, then publish the background.

Comment: @Buffy that’s it exactly. Perhaps I should have phrased it that clearly in the beginning...

Comment: The edit button is under your mouse.

Comment: @Buffy Yes, but this one is not nearly as enthusiastic about sharing. I'm just guessing at the voters' motivations, not saying which answer is better.

Comment: yes, opinion rules, @BryanKrause. I have a pretty high standard for down  voting. I don't down vote because I don't like an answer, or think another is better. I reserve downvotes for situations in which taking the advice would be actually dangerous for the OP. By that standard, this answer is actually better than the other. If you give up your IP without reason you can harm yourself. In a perfect world it wouldn't matter and publishing/sharing would be advisable, but I think we are not in that world.

Comment: @Buffy sincere apologies, edited. Sorry.

Comment: No apology needed, we are all just folks here.

Comment: In light of your edit, I have edited the reference to your answer out of mine.

Answer (score 7):

In most cases, yes you can, but you should ask your university if they have rules regarding hosting on websites/blogs with research products. Some places for example require that such a site is university hosted, can not be hosted abroad etc.

Should you do it? Absolutely, with the proviso that you should publish your paper first, or together with the code. With scientific results becoming more and more complex, it is often necessary to have access to various codes, for the purpose of reproduction. If your code is useful, it can also be quite profitable in terms of citations - remember to require people to cite your paper when they use your code.
Note that there are several journals (depending on your field) that actually specialize in publishing manuals for such public codes. CPC is a prominent example for physics (https://www.journals.elsevier.com/computer-physics-communications)

Answer (score 2):

Do not worry about copyright: copyright is about form not ideas, and you will not violate it unless you copy-paste copyrighted text.

On the other hand, some journals will only publish "original" work, and may not want your article if you have shared the results before. This strongly depends on the field and on the journal.